# Changing Text CSS On Scroll With jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement a header that becomes smaller once a user scrolls on my site. The logo and header part is done, but when I try to resize the text for the navigation, something becomes broken and the header no longer shrinks on scroll. Here is my broken code with the text resize: (#HOME is the ID for styles associated with a navigation link):

```
$(function () {
    $('#Header').data('size', 'big');
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('#Header').data('size') == 'big') {
            $('#Header').data('size', 'small');
            $('#Header').stop().animate({
                height: '60px'
            }, 600);
            $('#Logo').stop().animate({
                height: '40px',
                width: '40px'
            }, 600);
            $('#Logo:hover').stop().animate({
                height: '40px',
                width: '40px'
            }, 600);
            $('#HOME').stop().animate({
                font - size: '14px',
                top: '20px'
            }, 600);
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#Header').data('size') == 'small') {
            $('#Header').data('size', 'big');
            $('#Header').stop().animate({
                height: '100px'
            }, 600);
            $('#Logo').stop().animate({
                height: '85px',
                width: '81px'
            }, 600);
            $('#Logo:hover').stop().animate({
                height: '40px',
                width: '40px'
            }, 600);
            $('#HOME').stop().animate({
                font - size: '17px',
                top: '40px'
            }, 600);
        }
    }
});
```

Also, I'd appreciate if someone told me about a neater way to do this :P

Comment: Bind the scroll event inside your document.ready method.

Comment: Bic, I'm pretty (or completely) new to JS, can you maybe write out exactly what I need to change? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('#Header').data('size', 'big');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
            if ($('#Header').data('size') == 'big') {
                $('#Header').data('size', 'small');
                $('#Header').stop().animate({
                    height: '60px'
                }, 600);
                $('#Logo').stop().animate({
                    height: '40px',
                    width: '40px'
                }, 600);
                $('#Logo:hover').stop().animate({
                    height: '40px',
                    width: '40px'
                }, 600);
                $('#HOME').stop().animate({
                    font - size: '14px',
                    top: '20px'
                }, 600);
            }
        } else {
            if ($('#Header').data('size') == 'small') {
                $('#Header').data('size', 'big');
                $('#Header').stop().animate({
                    height: '100px'
                }, 600);
                $('#Logo').stop().animate({
                    height: '85px',
                    width: '81px'
                }, 600);
                $('#Logo:hover').stop().animate({
                    height: '40px',
                    width: '40px'
                }, 600);
                $('#HOME').stop().animate({
                    font - size: '17px',
                    top: '40px'
                }, 600);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The event needs to be bound in the `document.ready` or in this implementation `$(function () { ... });` method. Else it will likely bind before the control is ready.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, but doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Site is http://tremor.yt/Site/Creators.html for reference.

Comment: @user3517583 console says you have a syntax error. F12 to bring it up. Pretty sure it is the space in `font - size`.

Comment: Alright, the weird thing is that it works fine until I added the #HOME parameter. Is it possibly too much for the one section? Again, don't know anything about JS. Is there a better pay to organize it? (I'm going to have to add about 10 more of these sections.

Comment: @user3517583 I'd be impressed if you managed to do anything that would be too much. If you can make it modular, then go for it. Apply the same concepts as you would for anything other language. My suggestion would be to store your elements instead of re-retrieving them every time. Other than that, I can't make suggestions without seeing ALL of the code. Not really what this version of the site is for either.